# How can I detect wheather the number key, which is equivalent to the number in the int parameter, is pressed?

Tags: c#

I have the following lines of code in my Console Application in C#:

```
public static bool ReadKey(int key)
{
    /* Is the key represented by `key` pressed? */
}
```

How am I able to retrieve the right keyboard key?

Comment: C#? Java? Other? Please tag the useful things, like language. [tag:numbers], [tag:key], and [tag:pressed] should never be used.

Comment: What language and platform?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot its a console app in c#

Comment: Are you talking about keyboard keys? http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: What’s the context? Why do you need to check whether a key’s been pressed?

Comment: A piece of advice about tags: Always include what language you are using.

Comment: I want to invoke different methods according to the key that is pressed on the keyboard, so i need to know which key is pressed.

Comment: But what’s the real context? Are you building a game? A command-line utility? A keyhook-type thing?

Comment: It is a simulation of opening a Gate, which we are doing in school. So if the key "1" on the keyboard is pressed the OpenGate Method should be invoked and if "2" is pressed the Close Gate Method should be invoked etc.. So my idea was to have a while loop, where the condition is that the key "1" should be pressed. Something like while(ReadKey(1)){} (The Method is in the OP) and if it is pressed return true, else return false. So when the key is pressed it breaks out of the loop and continues with opening the Gate. In school we should open a Gate with the MicroController "K8055".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're application needs to be executing without pause and in that execution you need to check if key is pressed then: You can't do that in c# console application.

Take a look into first answer in this question. Same thing, you just need to modify it to support all needed keys instead of just arrow keys

[C# arrow key input for a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351258/c-sharp-arrow-key-input-for-a-console-app)

or

If the case is that you need to wait for user input, the simplest solution is Console.ReadKey();

Comment: Is it possible to do this Console.Readkey();, but if there is no input for like 5 seconds it breaks out of this Method? (I'm very new to programming, so this might be a stupid question)

Comment: Take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615/how-to-add-a-timeout-to-console-readline